# No spacing between bootstrap-labels with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When I am adding labels using ng-repeat from angular.js, they are shown without spacing.
Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/clTMOv?p=preview) which demonstrates it.

But if I add labels manually, just has copied html, then they are shown with whitespace.

Is there a way to add white space between labels without additional styling, as it does in pure bootstrap?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could change your HTML markup to this...

```
   <div class="panel-heading">
    My panel
    <span ng-repeat="tag in tags"><span class="label label-primary">{{tag}}</span> </span>
   </div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/113372

Comment: Thanks! Looks this is a best solution

Comment: This answer is also good to solved responsive problem. For example, if you repeat more than 15 labels, they were all stick together and going out from the column (not wrap inside)

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use CSS: Adjacent sibling selector

> Adjacent selector. It will select only the specified element that immediately follows the former specified element.

```
.label + .label {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: my main goal was to do it without extra CSS. But you solution also can work

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for this is that `ng-repeat` **does not** add space between your `<label>`
That's why the solution by Skelly works. 
The better way to ensure spacing is to use `&nbsp;` as `space` can be trimmed.

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <span class="label label-primary">{{tag}}</span>&nbsp;
</span>
```